# How does a natural change flats and sharps?

Tags: theory, notation, accidentals

If we have a G flat a natural gives a G, if we have a G sharp it gives a G, but what if we have a G double flat or double sharp? Especially if we are working in a key where G is already a flat or a sharp.

Comment: What is a becar?

Comment: Oh, a бекар is a natural! Please edit your question to use English names, as a Google search does not find _becar_ written in the Latin alphabet. I was lucky to guess that it was Russian and ran it through a translator.

Comment: ♮ unicode symbol could be most international way to do it

Comment: To answer a question adjacent to yours: If you have a Gbb and want the next note to be a Gb, just put a single flat sign next to the next note.

Comment: Can there be a double natural?

Comment: A double natural doesn't make any sense. One natural cancels out all other accidentals, including double sharps and double flats. One natural is the same as an infinite natural.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A natural sign always completely cancels any accidental that may be or have been on a note, and the note is played natural.

A G natural that comes after a G# is played as a G natural. A G natural following a G double sharp (Gx) is also played as a G natural.

Note that all the accidental symbols are treated the same way: they are absolute. A G# written after a previous G# is not played as a Gx, it's just played as a G#.

Comment: What if we double sharp a G and it becomes an A and then we want to play G# (Ab) do we place a flat after Gx?

Comment: @SovereignSun No. One would never write Gxb. That doesn't make sense. If you want a musician to play G#, write G#. No matter what notes come before a note written G#, if it's written G#, it should be played G#. The **only** time the note we play is based on a previous accidental is when there is *no accidental on the note*. If there's no accidental at all, then we go with the previous accidental within the measure or the key signature. As soon as you put any accidental on a note, that accidental overrides **everything** from before it.

Comment: So a natural basically reverts a note to the original key signature note?

Comment: @SovereignSun Sorry, no. A natural sign *also* cancels out the key signature. If you see a natural sign, you **always** play the completely **natural** note. Again, if a note has no accidental at all (a natural is an accidental) the you go back to the key signature or any previous accidental in the measure, if there is one. As soon as you put any accidental on, it immediately cancels out **any** prior accidentals and you play exactly the note written.

Comment: No, a natural makes a changed note into a note of simple letter name. So a former Gx,Gbb,G#Gb will be played as G natural when there's a natural before it. Even if there's a G# in the key sig. Also remember the next barline reverts ANY accidental to the key sig - which is different, maybe.

Comment: @Tim Any bar line does it? The first occurrence?

Comment: @SovereignSun Do you have any kind of teacher? This is a bit complicated to try to explain over the internet. All accidentals only last as long as the bar they are in. Once the bar ends, any further notes should be played as specified in the key signature, unless there are new accidentals in the next bar.

Comment: @ToddWilcox No. I'm trying to learn everything myself. Teachers are rather expensive. I have books but It's always so complex there!

Comment: @ToddWilcox So if we have a 4/4 bar and we place an accidental anywhere in that bar once a new bar of any other time signature starts the accidentals are all reverted to either the original key signature or a new one should it be defined?

Comment: @SovereignSun It's complex everywhere, that's why teachers can charge as much as they do. You should definitely spend time playing pieces that have hardly any accidentals and fairly simple key signatures so you get the feel for how it works. With the more simple pieces, you will usually hear it if it sounds wrong.

Comment: @SovereignSun Uh.. let's leave time signatures out of this. They have nothing to do with key signatures. Yes, when a new bar begins, everything goes back to the key signature.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I'm more of a composer rather than a player. I write my own music in Guitar Pro. Anyway I got your point. Am not silly learn quickly!

Comment: @SovereignSun - Yes, the NEXT barline, exactly as I said. ANY accidental in the previous barline is cancelled by that barline after it. Unequivocal. You nee the same note (accidental) again - you must write it in again. I respectfully suggest, judging by a lot of your questions here, that, if a teacher is unavailable, you furnish yourself with some ABRSM theory books, probably among the best for simple explanations. Grades I-V will help enormously. Then - please ask away, but you'll be asking with a lot more substance behind you, so answers will make more sense to you.

Comment: Please update answer according to new comments.

Comment: It's fairly clear that @SovereignSun is a beginner and talking about the current "standard" of musical notation, but just for completeness, some of his/her "mistakes" about the meaning of accidentals actually *were* "standard notation" in the 16th and 17th centuries, and that fact has caused quite a bit of confusion trying to interpret some old manuscripts and music text books.

Comment: @alephzero I Wouldn't say that I'm a beginner it's just that I never stumbled upon this before. I've been learning theory for many years with very little time for that but I don't learn it A-Z instead if I stumble upon something I look it up and read and ask about it. Most of what I recently stumble upon is really not much of a practical think as for I don't play so much really.

Answer (score 9):

This paragraph in the [Lilypond (notation software) docs](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/notation-big-page.en.html#accidentals) might be relevant:

> In accordance with traditional typesetting rules, a natural sign is
>   printed before a sharp or flat if a previous double sharp or flat on
>   the same note is canceled. (To change this behavior to contemporary
>   practice, set the *extraNatural* property to *f* in the *Staff* context.)

[image]

(the first measure corresponds to the "traditional" behaviour, the second to the "contemporary" - the played notes in both measures are the same, and they don't depend on the key)

This implies that:

- To **turn a double flat into a single flat** (regardless of the key) the traditional practice is to use a **natural-flat** pair.
- Alternatively (and more contemporarily), the natural can be ommited: a **single flat** is enough.
- A **single natural** sign always produces the **natural note** (regardless of previous accidentals or key)

Comment: In many printing fields there's a tendency to minimize "redundant" information without regard for whether it might make things more readable.  Is there any real advantage to the second approach above (using a single flat to cancel a double flat) besides saving ink?

Comment: @supercat I would say that a single flat is more readable, but I guess not everyone agrees

Comment: Incidentally, without the context, I would read "contemporary practice" as meaning "the practice at the time the music was written" rather than "modern practice".

Comment: Excellent point! This old/modern method also applies to key signatures.

Answer (score 4):

Remember your order of flats/sharps and that a flat or sharp is a "half tone" step.

The order for flats is

B E A D G C F

Sharps are backwards

F C G D A E B

Among other things this can be used as a guide of rarity. Under normal circumstances, to have a B# sound good, you need to also be playing F#, C#, G#, D#, A#, and E#.

Now when applied to say a Piano, there is no B# key. Half a "step" up from a B is a C. So to play a B# you would just play a C.

Now back to your question, it's rare but not unheard of to have a "double" accidental on pieces that are transposed poorly, or as a way of shoving more voices in the same staff.

So an F## would be played as  G (F + two half steps up).

I have never seen this in a well transposed piece. (Cramming more voices on a staff, or using F## instead of a G)

What is more Common is something like a A♭ major scale. B, E, and A are flat (order of flats)

So you get something, special in beginner pieces like

B♭, C, D, E♭, F, G, A♭, B♭

If written as

[image: Not Double flats]

These are not double flats, there just reminders to play flats.

[image: Not double flats]

Also in the second measure these are not double flats.

[image: Double flats]

Here in this example we have double flats.

C♭♭ is really a B♭ while the B♭♭ is really a A natural

C down half is a B down half is a B flat
B down half is a B♭ down half is a A natural

Lastly, I have seen, though rare, writing like this.

[image: Rare but seen]

These two measures sound the same, but the first, is in some opinions easier to read. Keep in mind the second double flat isn't needed, I just included it for demo purposes.

Normally when people write music in this style (example 3) it's due to a beleife that all As in a A flat major piece should be flat, but the music calls for a an A natural. i.e. It's a writing style, not a totally new note. This is fairly common. Even more so in keys that have many flats, but music that needs a "lesser" (more common) flat to be played neutral.

A more contrived example would be something like

[image: Naturals]

In the last measure, notes 3,4, 7, and 8 are all natural, while, 1 is flat because of the key signature, and note 5 had to have the flat reapplied to cancel out the natural from note 3.

All accidentals apply to the rest of the measure unless otherwise changed. So if we take out the naturals, You would play A♭, G, G, G, A♭, G, A♭, A♭.

Comment: Taking into account you last image: It's Ab, A, Ab, A and the second measure is also Ab, A, Ab, A because of the naturals and the 3rd 4th flat note is just a reminder?

Comment: Yep, exactly. 1 2

Comment: https://musescore.com/user/5379876/scores/3242531  You can hear it here.

Comment: This answer is better than mine. I was thinking of editing in examples but you've already done it. Well done coming into Music.SE and posting so much great content.

Comment: Double sharps arise from chromatically raising notes that are already "sharp", e.g. Fx is F# chromatically raised. Likewise double flats. They are correct spellings in some contexts; they do not necessarily arise from transposing poorly. If a composer wanted to shove two voices onto a stave, that would not excuse spelling notes wrongly -- some sheet music contains wrong spellings, but IME never merely in order to have two voices on one stave.

Comment: I did not mean that they come only form poor transposing. I mean that I have seen, though very rarely, poor transposing result in them. And that it's far more common that they result from a writing style (but are still correct).

Answer (score 2):

The raising and lowering by half step for sharps and flats applies only when relative to a natural tone. So, if you started with a `G♮` and then added a sharp `G♯`, the change is a half step ascent.

That is just a basic definition. It is especially applicable when first explaining the staff pitch letters and key signatures.

When you get into double sharps/flats we find out that accidentals are *literal*. You don't add/subtract by half steps with accumulated accidentals. Also, I don't think "cancel" is quite the right word, because that implies canceling to go back to a previous value. You just take the pitch letter from the staff and apply the accidental regardless of anything else around the note.

[image]

In those examples...

- the accidentals apply regardless of the key signature
- the accidentals apply regardless of preceding accidentals
- the two blue notes (notes on beat two) are `G` natural and `G` sharp
- enharmonically the first bar is a descent of two half steps (the natural sign did not merely lower by one half step)
- enharmonically the second bar is an ascent of three half steps (the sharp sign did not merely raise by one half step)

Don't accumulate, or add/subtract, half steps.

Just play literally what the note says: the pitch letter and its accidental.